# Protractor: For loop runs asynchronously causing test to run invalid validation

Tags: protractor

I am using For loop to iterate over a table. When a certain condition is met against a row, I will break from for loop. But as per my code, FOR seems to run asynchronously causing iteration in parallel which I do not intend my program to do. Can someone help in working with this problem which I assume is due to promise resolution.

```
element.all(by.css('tbody tr')).then(function(rows){
    for(var i = 1; i < (rows.length); i++) {
        var count=0;
        var pass=0;
        //TEST VALUES BELOW
        var appNameCreated="Test App 534";
        //TEST VALUES ABOVE
        console.log(i);
        element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+ i +']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')).getText().then(function(appname){
            console.log(i,appname);
            if(appname==appNameCreated){
                console.log(appname,appNameCreated,i);
                element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+ i +']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(6)')).getText().then(function(result){
                    console.log(result,i);
//                  if (result==data.resultSubmit){
                    if (result=="Activated"){
                        pass += 1;
                        element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+ i +']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')).element(by.css('a')).click().then(function(){
                            browser.sleep(4000);
                        });
                        element(by.id("btnTab3")).element(by.xpath('span')).click();
                        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]'))),15000);                                   browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("button-basic"))),15000);
                        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("button-basic"))),15000);
                        element(by.id("button-basic")).click();
                        element.all(by.css('ul[class="dropdown-menu"]')).each(function(item1){
                            item1.element(by.css('li:nth-child(7)')).element(by.css('a')).click();
                        })
                        element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+i+']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(6)')).getText().then(function(resultFin){
                            console.log(resultFin);
                            browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+ i +']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)'))).perform();
                            expect(resultFin).toBe(data.resultFinal);
                        })
                    }
                })  
            }
        })
        if(pass==1){
            break;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Please show the HTML code of your table and what you want to do on the table, maybe there is more simple approach for your purpose.

Comment: I have protractor test which will iterate on a table with 6 columns. I am iterating on the table using FOR on each row, and then search for specific text in first column. If matches, check the status in 6th column, if it is set to Activate, click the matched row which will take it to another page, perform an operation, come back to table page, reiterate on the same table and check for that specific text and validate the final status to be Activate again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Array-like object's `reduce()` to iterate the rows and use `Promise.reject()` once the row meet your condition to break the loop.

Because you reject the promise, you should use `Promise.catch()` to capture it, and click the matched row to enter next page and do operations , then back to table page inside the `catch()`

```
let appName = 'Test App 534',
    tbl = element(by.xpath(
            '/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table')),
    rows = tbl.all(by.css('tbody > tr'));

rows.reduce((initValue, row, rowIndex)=>{
    return row.all(by.css('td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(6)'))
        .getText()
        .then((txts)=>{
            console.log('row ' +rowIndex+ ', txts: ' + txts)
            if(txts[0] === appName && txts[1] === 'Activated') {
                console.log('this is matched row');
                // when the row meet the condition
                // reject a promise with the row index of matched row.
                // Promise.reject() will break out the loop
                // and code will run into the following catch() section
                return Promise.reject(rowIndex);
            }
        })
}, -1)
.catch((rowIndex)=>{
    // use catch() to obtains the row index of matched row via
    // Promise.reject(rowIndex) in previous rows.reduce()

    console.log('matched row:' + rowIndex);
    // click on matched row to enter next page
    rows.get(rowIndex).element(by.css('td:nth-child(1) > a')).click();
    browser.sleep(4000);

    // do other operations and back to the table page
    ...

    return rowIndex;  
    // still return the rowIndex for as argument for
    // the following then() which we will check 
    // the status of matched row is still Activated
})
.then((rowIndex)=>{
    console.log('matched row2:' + rowIndex);
    console.log("Check matched row's status is still 'Activated'")
    let status = rows.get(rowIndex).element(by.css('td:nth-child(6)')).getText();
    expect(status).toEqual('Activated');
    return browser.sleep(5000)
})
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Yong for resolving my prolonged issue. Hats off. This did work. Can you please provide some good tutorial for Protractor for understanding .reduce() and promise handling

Answer (score 0):

Update your code:
- change promise resolving using `async ... await`
- change `var` to `let, const`
- counting in a loop should begin from `0` instead of `1`
- change `==` to `===`
- `.each()` does not work properly with async operations as `click()`
Questions:
- from where you take data.resultSubmit ?

```
const rows = await element.all(by.css('tbody tr'));
const appNameCreated = "Test App 534";
let count = 0;
let pass = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  console.log('Index is ', i);
  const appname = await element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+ i +']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')).getText();
  console.log('App name for current loop is ', appname);
  if(appname === appNameCreated) {
    console.log('App name is the same as created app name for loop with index ', i);
    const result = await element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+ i +']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(6)')).getText();
    console.log('Result for current run is ' result);
    if (result === data.resultSubmit && result === "Activated") {                                 
      pass += 1;
      await element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+ i +']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)')).element(by.css('a')).click();
      await browser.sleep(4000);
    });
    await element(by.id("btnTab3")).element(by.xpath('span')).click();
    await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]'))),15000);                                   
    await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("button-basic"))),15000);
    await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("button-basic"))),15000);
    await element(by.id("button-basic")).click();
    const menus = await element.all(by.css('ul[class="dropdown-menu"]'));
    const amount = await menus.count();
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
     const item = await menus.get(i);
     await item.element(by.css('li:nth-child(7)')).element(by.css('a')).click();
    }
    const resultFin = await element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+i+']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(6)')).getText();
   console.log('resultFin is ', resultFin);
   await browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.xpath('/html/body/gft-root/section/div[2]/app-onboard-list/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+ i +']')).element(by.css('td:nth-child(1)'))).perform();
   expect(resultFin).toBe(data.resultFinal);
 })
}
 })  
 }
 })
if(pass ===1 ){
 break;
                }
            }
        })
```

I have tried to remove as much mistakes as I can. Your code is bad because you don't split this BIG amount of "What a hell is there???" to smaller functions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I am just a month old in automation of WebApps through automation so pardon me. Await is not allowed as per eclipse. Any comments on this.

Comment: `async ... await` it is not about eclipse or other IDE, it's about node version. Find in settings and use higher node version